# Print value of variable in tensor flow from a member function of a class

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I have a viable defined as follows which is also the weight matrix for a regular neural net.

```
 W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([feature_space_size, hidden1], stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(feature_space_size),dtype=tf.float64), name='W1')
```

How can I print its value while I am debugging ? The issue is that its defined in a constructor and I need to access it in a member function of the same class. I tried fetching using

```
tf.get_variable('W1',[4,300])
```

But I am not able to print its value using self.sess.run(). Please advise. There should really be a simpler way to print the value of variables. And moreover, it seems likee after I do get_variable, its no longer in the op graph for TF.

Comment: Try `print(sess.run("W1:0"))`

Comment: good suggestion. However this is not a general answer

Answer (score 1):

use this line of code to make a list of the variables that tensor flow assigns to all the tf.Variables().

```
v = [a.name for a in tf.trainable_variables()]
```

The string `a.name` contains a string part of which is the variable name.

The value can be accesses by using `sess.run(a.name)`